# Необработанное исключение по адресу 0x7A7536AD (vcruntime140.dll) в Project1ssss.exe: Я уже пробовал кидать файлы в директорию проекта не помогло

Tags: c++, sfml

```
Необработанное исключение по адресу 0x7A7536AD (vcruntime140.dll) в Project1ssss.exe
```

Я уже пробовал кидать файлы в директорию проекта - не помогло.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace sf;

int main(){
    ContextSettings seting;
    seting.antialiasingLevel = 8;
    RenderWindow window(VideoMode(640, 480), "Picture");
    while (window.isOpen()) {
        Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event)) {
            if (event.type == Event::Closed) {
                window.close();
            }
        }
        window.clear(Color(218, 192, 167, 0));                
        Texture texture;
        texture.loadFromFile("C:\\ImageBlyat\\JA.jpg");
        Sprite sprite(texture); 
        window.draw(sprite);
        window.display();
    }
    return 0;   
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Я убрал цифры в пути к файлу и всё работает